# Laplacian in a perforated domain with non-homogenous boundary conditions. Link with the existence of a suited extension function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $A,Q$ be two regular bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such as $\overline{A}\subset Q$. Let $\varphi \in C^\infty(\overline{A})$ be fixed data.

We want to give a meaning to the following problem:

Find $u$ such as it is a (weak) solution of:

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u &= 0 &&\text{in } Q{\setminus A}\\
u&= \varphi &&\text{on } \partial A\\
u &= 0 &&\text{on } \partial Q
\end{aligned}\tag{$\star$}\label{eq:star}
\end{gather}

If we want to give a meaning to this problem and find a solution, we take $\xi \in H^1_0(Q)$ such as (using Sobolev extension operator for example if it is possible):

- $\xi=\varphi$ in $A$
- $\|\nabla \xi\|_{L^2(Q)} \leq C \|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2(A)}$

With this $\xi$, we can denote $v \in H^1_0(Q \setminus A)$ the solution of the following well-posed problem:

$$
-\Delta v = \Delta \xi \quad\text{in } Q \setminus A.\tag{$\star \star$}\label{eq:sstar}
$$

Then we say that the function $u:= v + \xi \in H^1_0(Q \setminus A) + \xi$ is a solution of \eqref{eq:star} (extending $v$ to zero in $A$).

Is this the good way to define a weak solution of \eqref{eq:star}? How would you do it ? Also, can we prove something like:

*There exists such a $\xi$ if and only if the problem \eqref{eq:star} is well-defined.*

I feel like I'm not really understanding the problem \eqref{eq:star}. Any help or advice are welcomed. I'm also wondering if such a function $\xi$ can always be found, depending on the geometry of $A$.

Comment: What is your definition of "($\star$) is well defined"?

Comment: @gerw, actually this is where i'm confused about. I know how to give a meaning to $(\star)$ in a strong sense. However, when i want to give a weak meaning in variational form, I feel like I need to use the problem $(\star \star)$ through the function $\xi$... If you had to give a definition of $(\star)$ is well-defined, what would it be ?